# Is combining junctions possible?

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction

When connecting two dass-clauses, the latter begins with "und":

> Dass ich das konnte
> **und dass** es existiert,
> ist gut.

Did we not combine junctions right there?

> **Aber wenn** das nicht klappt,
> komm zu mir.
> **Und obwohl** das nicht klappt,
> versuchte er es erneut.

I am aware that  Konjunktionaladverb + junction is possible:

> **Und trotzdem** klappt es nicht.

Duden Randnummer 864 states **that junctions can't be combined**. How are the two examples I gave to understand, then? Is "und" and "aber" not working as a conjunction in the example, or, could one of the connectors be seen as a Konjunktionaladverb?

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine two or more Konjunktionaladverbien.

- <strike>Er bleibt stehen, **trotzdem gleichwohl** es losgeht.</strike>

If you want to do such a thing, you have to use a list

- Er bleibt stehen, **trotzdem und gleichwohl** es losgeht.

This rule does not apply to true conjunctions that do not occupy a field in the clause.

- Er bleibt stehen, **auch trotzdem** es losgeht.

Comment: obwohl is a subjunction. Your examples don't match your first sentence.

Comment: You are right. I had *dennoch* in there originally. Let's use *gleichwohl* instead.